# AppEngine BlobStore cant upload blobs since update to 1.6.1 from 1.5.5 | getUploads(req) and getUploadedBlobs(req) both fail

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, eclipse-plugin, blobstore

I'm using GAE (Java version) for my website and I'm developing in Eclipse with the Google Plugin. It all worked perfectly and actually the site is successfully deployed on AppEngine. The problem started when I updated the plugin and SDK to the new version from 1.5.5 to 1.6.1 specifically with the blobstoreservice.

I CANT get the BlobKeys from the request.

The deployed version uses

```
blobstoreservice.getUpladedBlobs(HttpServletRequest)
```

but since the update to 1.6.1 it throws

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

although it compiles without problems, only a "deprecated" warning.

Given I got the "deperecated" warning I tried with the new recommended method

```
blobstoreservice.getUploads(HttpServletRequest)
```

but this one throws `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` and it compiles with NO warnings.

Any ideas of what's happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

OK, this took me not that much time to solve.

Apparently the problem was that the Google Plugin for Eclipse didn't remove the old AppEngine SDK jar from the WAR/WEB-INF/lib directory. Just had to delete the jars corresponding to the 1.5.5 SDK (leaving those corresponding to 1.6.1) and DONE!!!

The strangest thing was that on my other app engine projects the old jars where automatically deleted. Just one of those strange software glitches I'll never understand.